# How to Modify Existing Keys in Joi Object

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

Joi validation does not support modification of existing object keys.

I am using Joi validation for parent and child classes. The validation for the parent is the base validation for all children, but each child has specific restrictions or additional fields.
I want to be able to just take my parent Joi object and be able to modify existing keys to fit certain restrictions.

```
//Declare base class with an array at most 10 elements
const parent = {
    myArray: Joi.array().max(10)
}
//Now declare child with minimum 1 array value
const child = parent.append({
    foo: Joi.string(),
    myArray: Joi.array().min(1).required()
})
```

The above code works as expected - meaning the child object does not keep the .limit(10) restriction applied to the parent.
But, I want it such that it does. I'm sure append is not the right function to use here, but I am not sure of how to do this.
I want my resulting child validation to look like:

```
const child = {
    foo: Joi.string(),
    myArray: Joi.array().max(10).min(1).required()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
const child = parent.append({
    foo: Joi.string(),
    myArray: parent.myArray.min(1).required()
});
```

Just tried:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const parent = {
  x: Joi.array().max(10).required()
};

const child = Object.assign({}, parent, {
  x: parent.x.min(1).required(),
  y: Joi.string()
});

Joi.validate({
  x: [],
  y: 'abc'
}, child); // fails as .min(1) not satisfied

Joi.validate({
  x: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  y: 'abc'
}, child); // fails as .max(10) not satisfied

Joi.validate({
  x: [1],
  y: 'abc'
}, child); // OK
```

Tried with a fresh `npm i joi` (package says: `"joi": "^14.3.1"`), on Node v8.10.0. Or maybe the example you gave is too trivial to reflect your real scenario?

Comment: Yeah Joi does not support key access like that from the parent object. That is basically what I want to be able to do

Comment: Just tried, worked as intended... see my edit above.

Comment: ah, I was usin `Joi.object()` to create my parent/children (my example didn't show that correctly). Doing that removes the ability to access elements via `parent.key`. But the way you did it, with just vanilla objects, works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: In some rare cases you have to deal with pre-built Joi objects (like fetching an item declared as nested in an array), then you can use the dirty way: `x: parent._inner.children.find((e) => { return e.key === 'x'; }).schema.min(1).required()`. (I remembered I had to do that once, and I just tested it still works on the latest version, without altering `parent.x`'s behavior.) Enjoi!

Comment: Ahh okay, that _dirty_ fix will actually help me a ton - I'll just toss it into a helper function. Thanks!